# Can someone please explain how to embed a provisioning profile into an Enterprise build of an iOS app? (Searching didn't help)

Tags: xcode, provisioning, enterprise

I'm going insane here and any help is appreciated. I am trying to do this:

Build an app for Enterprise distribution and install it on devices without them needing their UDID registered and without being development devices with provisioning profiles. This app will go out to specific users via Airwatch. I cannot use any third party tools like Testflight.

Here is what I have done:

-I have an enterprise account.
-I have a team provisioning profile of type development and a distribution profile and have verified they are both in keychain. These are wildcard profiles, I'm not sure if that matters. 
-When building the project for release I have the debug set to the Team profile (development) and the release set to the distribution profile. 
-I then do a regular build on the app, and then an archive.
-When I save the archive I save it for "Enterprise or Ad-Hoc". (Enterprise is what I want).
-I then check "Save for Enterprise distribution" and enter my app URL (which I assume is the com.blahblah.app) and also put in the App name. I do not want to release this over a server, I just want to make a stand alone that can be given to our air watch administrator.

When I try and use the Apple Configurator I get the error: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

From my understanding I don't need a provisioning profile because it should be bundled with the app when I build the archive correct? Or am I misunderstanding the Enterprise account ability.

All I want to do is be able to create a standalone with the provisioning profile embedded so I can use the Apple Configurator to test the stand alone before sending it to the Airwatch Admin.

All of the posts I found regarding this are outdated so I am hoping someone can help. I am using Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: I am having this same issue. My apps work fine when installed manually, and the provisioning profile works fine that way. I can also set up the machines, load it manually, enable the app, and sync using "supervise" and it works fine that way as well. Just not during the "prepare" step.

Comment: Did you select the correct provisioning profile while exporting the archive?